Define maximum of matrix entries in Lean4
In Lean4 I would like to define a function max that finds the largest entry of an $n\times n$ matrix with entries in a LinearOrderedField:
import Mathlib.Algebra.Field.Defs
import Mathlib.Algebra.Order.Group.Defs
import Mathlib.Data.Matrix.Basic
import Mathlib.Data.Matrix.Notation

variable (F : Type*) [LinearOrderedField F]
variable (n :  ℕ ) 
#check Matrix (Fin n) (Fin n) F -- gets accepted

def maxMatrixEntry (M : Matrix (Fin n) (Fin n) F) : F := ?

variable (A : Matrix (Fin n) (Fin n) F)
#check maxMatrixEntry A -- This claims A has the wrong type, why?

$$
maxMatrixEntry (M) := \max_{i : Fin \ n,\ j : Fin \ n} \{ M i j \}
$$
I don't know how to approach this problem, I tried reading through the docs. Where can I learn such things?
edit: Thanks to Mark Pocks answer, the Matrices are now of size n x n.

In Lean, the first two arguments to Matrix aren't actually integers m x n that define the size of the matrix, as you've now found out -- they are the types that let you index into the matrix. For all intents and purposes, a matrix Matrix m n F is just a function from m to n to F (and in fact, this is exactly how matrices are defined in the source code):
def Matrix (m : Type u) (n : Type u') (α : Type v) : Type max u u' v :=
  m → n → α

So, if you wanted to supply any natural indices, you'd write Matrix ℕ ℕ F. However, we can do better -- as you note, the fact that they are finite integers preferably limited to some range is useful, so there is a datatype Fin n which is the type of naturals in [0, n). You can access that type by importing Mathlib.Data.Matrix.Notation.
Now we have the difficulty of looping over Fin n, since we can't just get a Fin n from a random natural number. The easiest way of doing this is using List.finRange, which gives you a list of all the numbers in Fin n. Then, you can deal with the problem either functionally or imperatively, depending on which you prefer, something like either
for i in List.finRange n do
  -- (operations)

(fun i => --operations) <$> List.finRange n

As for where to learn about these things, I wish I had a good answer to that one as well, but for this specific question I looked at the docs (just a different page than you linked) and the source code of mathlib (https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4/blob/master/Mathlib/Data/Matrix/Basic.lean).

Cool, thank you so much. I adjusted the code a bit to include Fin n. Do you know how I can iterate over i,j : Fin n? to find the max?

Edited the post accordingly!
